# HTML GET with & in a parameter

Tags: html

I fured out, that I got a problem with the "&" in a parameter, because the browser is interpreting it as a new parameter. Using urlencode doesn't help.
Example: `http://www.example.com?artist=Brooks & Dunn&title=Maria`

Is there a way to go around that problem?

Comment: What do you mean "using urlencode doesn't help"? That's *literally* the solution you need.

Comment: "Using urlencode doesn't help" if your application fails with the parameter `Brooks%20%26%20Dunn` then you should recode something

Comment: I would go as far as turning it around - if you have an application that does not interpret `&` as the parameter separator in URLs, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. urlencode - urldecode works, I found my problem thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use URL encoding to encode unsafe characters in an URL.
`http://www.example.com?artist=Brooks%20%26%20Dunn&title=Maria`

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding